# Adding even / odd elements in *argv[] to arrays

Tags: c++, c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I'm fairly new to C++ and I'm making a simple program which takes values and units as system arguments and converts them all to a single unit. The command line execution and input goes something like this:

```
./unit_conv 3 feet 5 inches centimeters
```

The values and units are separated by spaces, and the final argument is the unit I want to convert everything to.

My approach to get input is to add all even elements of *argv[] before the last element to an integer array called 'values', and add all odd ones to a character pointer array called 'units'. Below is my attempted implementation:

```
if (argc % 2 == 0) {
  char * desiredUnit  = argv[argc - 1];
  int values[argc];
  char * units[argc];

  int j;
  int k;
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 1) {
      values[j] = atoi(argv[i]);
      j++;
    }
    else {
      units[k] = argv[i];
      k++
    }
  }
}
```

Upon the execution I mentioned above, I get the following:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I know the seg fault is occurring within my for loop. I don't see how the program is attempting to access restricted memory, though. I've been stuck with this one for quite awhile.

Hopefully I provided enough info, but if my question is too vague please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't initialize `j` and `k`. Depending on the C implementation, they may be zero or a completely random value.

Comment: Assume they are indeterminate. If they are set to 0 it won't be for the convenience of the coder, but for privacy.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Note that variable length arrays are not standard c++, you should use `std::vector` instead

Comment: Works now! What a mundane mistake on my part. I was under the notion that variables are by default initialized to zero.

Comment: @Alan Birtles, aren't vectors only used if the size is expected to change often?

Comment: No, vectors should also be used where the size is unknown at compile time, VLAs are non standard and can easily lead to stack overflows, vectors help prevent them by being heap allocated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using STL?

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> units{};
std::vector<int> values{};

for (std::size_t i {1}; i < argc; ++i) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        units.push_back(std::string{argv[i]});
    } else {
        values.push_back(std::atoi(argv[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: A far cleaner approach. This makes the index counters {j} and {k} arbitrary. Thanks Ayman!